# Is there a .Net MVC solution out there that supports shared usage of Views, both on server and client?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js

I was wondering about this a couple of weeks ago when looking at http://derbyjs.com/ and meteor.js.
What I like about these platforms is that these support sharing of (HTML)templates on both server (like ASP.Net MVC Views) AND client for browsers that support JavaScript.
Basically combining ASP.Net MVC server side rendering of HTML and the ASP.Net Single Page App architecture. So that we only have to maintain view / template code in one place and have it available for server-side rendering as well as client side MVC / MVVM.
Is there a solution like this available or in the works somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing and I came across a few options:

1. A simple approach but limited because it's "logic-less templates" are the mustache templates - they have .net nustache
2. Ports of Razor View Engine to Javascript like Javascript + Razor == Jazor? -

   - and there is another port maybe more active on github of this by kirbysayshi/vash - https://github.com/kirbysayshi/vash
3. The Spark View Engine - which some of the .net heros like Scott Allen and Hanselman talking about it...  and a post here http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/03/12/client-rendering-views-with-spark-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx that shows how the same Spark view is possible on the server and client.

Maybe there are more... as this seems to be common desire to unify the View code to write once and run on client/server.

If I was to pick now based on the activity of the projects on GitHub, the kirbysayshi/vash has continuous commits and it very active!  Since Vash is a port of the Razor it may be the most accessible and most mature at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any.

I remember looking for one a year ago and I couldn't found any.

It all depends on your app, but you should achieve performance good enough if you keep rendering on the server side and use ajax to bring back partial views so you can refresh parts of your page.

The trick is to create small actions that will render parts of the page (instead of rendering partial views through `Html.RenderPartial`). You can then call the same actions through ajax to refresh parts of your page.